# SCCM - Feature Update 20H1 not visible in Software Center

Tags: windows, windows-10, sccm, automatic-updates, sccm-2012-r2

Good morning fellow SCCM admins and enthusiasts!

I have deployed the Windows 10 20H1 Feature Update via SCCM to a collections of computers running Windows 10 1903 and Windows 10 1909. It is a required deployment.

[image: FeatureUpdate Deployment]

The deployments are visible in SCCM Configuration Console on the computer object:

[image]

However nothing is visible in Software Center on the target computer itself.

[image]

I am a bit lost at this point and would need to investigate why some devices are not showing the required update, although it's deployed to them.
Where would I start looking into this?

Comment: Try this first, an a target computer, go 'Control Panel > Configuration Manager'
Select the 'Actions' tab.
Select 'Machine Policy Retrieval & Evaluation Cycle', then click Run Now.
Select 'Software Inventory Cycle', then click Run Now.
Select 'Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle', then click Run Now.
The available software in Software Center should update soon. Pressing the F5 key within the Software Center window will refresh the list.
Let me know if it updates or not.

Comment: @NetServOps Thanks, will try it out. Didnt see your comment until now and I am off a week, so earliest I can check is next week. Appreciate the help!